# Lightning:empAPI support for community

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible change data capture event in LWC embeded in a lightning community using empAPI?

Answer (score 1):

As per this documentation [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation), emAPI is only supported in lightning experience.

[image]

Comment: You can roll your own... but it's not easy